# Coercivity and spectral gap: understanding the equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, kinematics, coercive

I am referring to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0609050.pdf), p. 21.

First, there is the following definition of *coercivity*:

> Let $L$ be an unbounded operator on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ with kernel $\mathcal{K}$ and let $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ be another Hilbert space continuously and densely embedded in $\mathcal{K}^\perp$, endowed with a scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}}$ and a Hilbertian norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}}$. The operator $L$ is said to be $\lambda$-coercive on $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ if
> $$
> \forall h\in\mathcal{K}^\perp\cap D(L),\quad\Re\langle Lh,h\rangle_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}}\geq\lambda\Vert h\Vert^2_{\tilde{\mathcal{H}}},
> $$
> where $\Re$ stands for the real part. The operator $L$ is said to be coercive on $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ if it is $\lambda$-coercive on $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}$ for some $\lambda>0$.

Afterwards, it is said that

> [..] the most standard situation is when $\tilde{\mathcal{H}}=\mathcal{K}^\perp\simeq \mathcal{H}/\mathcal{K}$.

Moreover, in this particular case, it is said that

> [..] **it is equivalent to say that $L$ is coercive on $\mathcal{K}^\perp$, or that the symmetric part of $L$ admits a *spectral gap***.

Could you please explain to me why this equivalence holds?

As far as I understand, spectral gap means that there exists some $c>0$ such that
$$
\sigma(L)\subset\{0\}\cup [c,\infty)
$$

However, from this, I can neither conclude that $L$ is coercive on $\mathcal{K}^\perp$ (nor vice versa).

My "feeling" is that this has something to do with the relationship between the spectrum of $L$ and its numerical range (but I only know this for self-adjoint bounded operators and this seems to be another situation here).

Comment: Simply because $Re(Lh,h)=2(Sh,h)$ where $S=(L+L^*)/2$ is the symmetric part of $S$.

Comment: Could you be a bit more detailed? Your hint does not explain to me the equivalence.

Comment: Sure, do you agree on what I wrote above or does that need more explanation? The rest is essentially the definition of spectral gap.

Comment: A few more explanations would be great. I mean, for a complex number $x=a+ib$, it is clear that $\Re x=a=\frac{x+x^*}{2}$, where $x^*=a-ib$. But here, $L$ is an operator.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is anything deep here.

Note that

\begin{align}
\Re \langle Lh,h \rangle &= \frac{1}{2} \left ( \langle Lh,h \rangle + \langle Lh,h \rangle^\ast \right )\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2} \left ( \langle Lh,h \rangle + \langle h,Lh \rangle \right ) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left ( \langle Lh,h \rangle + \langle L^\ast h,h \rangle \right ) \\
&= \langle Sh,h \rangle
\end{align}

Where I just defined the symmetric part of $L$ to be

$$S = \frac{1}{2} \left ( L + L^\ast \right ). $$

The definition of spectral gap depends a bit on the context.
It seems your definition is: the symmetric operator $A$ admits a spectral gap $\gamma \ge c$ if

$$
\sigma(A) \subset \{0\} \cup [c, \infty).$$

Note that we must require the operator to be symmetric or the spectrum need not be real.

The above definition is equivalent to the fact that

$$
\langle Ah,h \rangle \ge c \langle h,h \rangle \quad \forall h \notin \ker (A)
$$

Now the equation

$$
\Re \langle Lh,h \rangle  = \langle Sh,h \rangle \ge \lambda \langle h, h \rangle >0
$$

means that $h$ is not in the kernel of $S$ and so it means that $S$ has a spectral gap at least as big as $\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe you could add the remaining step? I still do not see the desired equivalence (probably because I do not know the definition of spectral gap, in particularlary for symmetric unbounded operators like $S$).

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: And that's exactly the point where I am struggeling: Why is $\sigma(A)\subset\{0\}\cup [c,\infty)$ equivalent to $\langle Ah,h\rangle\geq c\langle h,h\rangle$ for all $h\notin\textrm{ker}(A)$?

Comment: @Icv Could you comment on my last question in order to be able to close this thread successfully?